# Access only lowest nested value in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

Example of structure in a document in MongoDB:

```
{'OtherData':...},
{'Top':
    {'A': 'ValueA'}
    {'B': 'ValueB'},
}
```

I want to query and project value for the `A` key so I used the project to just return `Top.A`

```
db.find({},{'Top.A':1, '_id':0}
```

However this just returns:

```
{'Top':{'A':'ValueA'}}
```

I want it to just return `ValueA`. I understand I can access it since it is a dictionary but I want to access it directly in the query.

Comment: just try `{ "A": "$Top.A", "_id": 0 }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `aggregate` pipeline of MongoDB, it will be especially handy if You'd like to work on more complicated documents.

In your case You want to use `$project` step like so:

```
db.base.aggregate([
   {'$project':
       { 'A':'$Top.A'}
   }
])
```